# how to call a value of a dropdownlist from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

```
        this.roomChoice.Title = " Select a classroom: ";
        this.roomChoice.Subtitle = "";
        if (frmRoomMaint.cbxRoomsChoice = null)
        {
            SetRoomOptions();
        }
        else
        {
            //cbxRooms is the dropdownlist on frmWizard
            cbxRooms = frmRoomMaint.cbxRoomsChoice;
            cbxRooms.Enabled=false;
        }
```

This is the error message:

```
Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

i'm creating a wizard that can be called from the menu, or by right clicking on a certain form after a room has been selected from a dropdownlist. if the wizard is opened from the form i want the dropdownlist in the wizard to already have the same room selected and to be disabled. if it is selected from the menu the user is free to choose any room in the dropdownlist.

please let me know if any clarification is needed. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need some more information to answer this.

What line in your code example is causing the error?

Is the error happening at Run Time or Design Time?

If `frmRoomMaint` is the name of your *other form*, then the error is saying you must create an instance of it before you use it.

```
frmRoomMaint form = new frmRoomMaint();

this.roomChoice.Title = " Select a classroom: ";
this.roomChoice.Subtitle = "";
if (form.cbxRoomsChoice = null)
{
   SetRoomOptions();
}
else
{
   //cbxRooms is the dropdownlist on frmWizard
   cbxRooms = form.cbxRoomsChoice;
   cbxRooms.Enabled=false;
}
```

I'm guessing there are other errors too, but this is probably your first error - without having more information!

Comment: that was my only error. all i needed was                                    frmRoomMaint form = new frmRoomMaint();

Comment: The hardest part is staring at the question long enough to realize where a simple error might be. Glad this worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading values in a different form from another, I suggest you to store shared data in  a `static` class, so these values are visible through all your application.

```
public static class SharedData
{
    public static string SelectedRoom
    {
        set;
        get;
    }

    // other data

}
```